# workbook.Worksheets.Clear(); ruining size of the cell in excel

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

```
        i = (i + 1) % 100;
        {

            worksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0, 1] = 10000;
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);

            string myFileName = String.Format("{0}__{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), ".csv");
            string myFullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\", myFileName);
            workbook.Save(myFileName);

            worksheet.Cells[i, 0] = new Cell(DateTime.Now, @"yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss");
            worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = new Cell(DataFromCOM);
            worksheet.Cells[i, 2] = new Cell(val);


            //workbook.Worksheets.Clear(); 

        }
```

When I run `workbook.Worksheets.Clear();` it removes all the formatting of the cells.  It eliminates my cells column width and implements an incorrect formula, putting numbers that does not make sense instead of the date.

Comment: What do you mean by putting not date? I assume the format of the cell is incorrect that's why it is throwing up 'numbers that does not make sense'

Comment: it shows not date 2017-07-12_12:43-30 but it shows 41466,52785.
without putting  workbook.Worksheets.Clear() it shows correct, but the problem is, it program creates too many sheets in excel file , that are not needed.

Comment: Any idea, how it could be changed?

Comment: Yes but I assume the .Clear() probably removes the formatting too. By Clear you just want to remove the text or just blank it in total?

Comment: I want to delete extra sheets, but keep all the data of first page with bigger size of cells (10000, not 3000, that it gives)

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean by bigger size of cells?

Comment: worksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0, 1] = 10000;

if i put clear(), it becomes smaller. That's why date is not be able to be written properly.

Comment: worksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0, 1] = 10000;

if i put clear(), it becomes smaller. That's why date is not be able to be written properly.

Comment: Try Cells.ClearContents [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4178ed9f-3ddf-457f-8747-debd41b907e2/excel-clear-contents-for-a-sheet?forum=vsto)

Comment: Sadly, It doesn't work for me still.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help any more. I do not know.

Comment: maybe there should be different placement for one or another function?

Answer (score 0):

```
        workbook.Worksheets.Clear();
        workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet); 

        n++;
        {

                worksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0, 1] = 10000;

                string myFileName = String.Format("{0}__{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), ".csv");
                string myFullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\", myFileName);
                workbook.Save(myFileName);

                worksheet.Cells[n, 0] = new Cell(DateTime.Now.ToString( @"HH:mm:ss"));
                worksheet.Cells[n, 1] = new Cell(DataFromCOM);
                worksheet.Cells[n, 2] = new Cell(val);




            }
```